# How to stop move of graph when move touch on stock chart graph in highcharts with ionic 2 and angular 2?

Tags: angular, highcharts, ionic2

I used stock chart of Highcharts component with Ionic 2 and angular 2. I have facing one issue which is when I move touch on graph, graph is also move without next or previous data. I want to stop this means on touch move, graph should be not move.
I really appreciate if someone help me.

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.panning
Does this help?

Comment: I got the solution for this. chart.panning is not used, I used chart.pinchType:'' for this solution.